# Finding the values of $y$ between which this inequality is true for all $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

I am trying to find a way to find values of $y\in[0,1]$ for which the following inequality is true for all $x\in[0,1]$ ($x=\cos\theta$ with $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$).

$$k\times\sqrt{1+\frac{p^2}{q^2}\frac{(1-y^2)^3}{(1-yx)^4}}\left(\frac{a(1-y^2)}{x(1-yx)}-\frac{b}{x}\right)\geq\frac{2\pi}{q}$$

The solution will depend on the positive variables $a, b, k, p, q$, and will be used as part of a tool that will be provided with these values when it runs.

Hopefully, the following picture clarifies what I'm looking for.

[image]

Thus far, I have tried rearranging and expanding everything but came to a very long 8th order polynomial which I was unable to reduce down, and knowing no other way to approach it I hit a dead end.

I'm hoping that someone here can point me in the direction of an approach that will get me closer to a solution. If not exact, approximate will do - though an exact method would make my day!

Comment: Is this supposed to be $k$ times the square root or the $k$-th root?

Comment: yes, $k$ times the square root - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Instead of looking for where a degree 8 polynomial takes negative values, what if you differentiate and try to find where the derivative is zero. Do you see a way of factoring the derivative?

Comment: Also, knowing the orders of magnitude of the parameters $k,p,q,a,b$ might help to approximate your function.  It might be true that the square root part either dominates or is negligible

Comment: I did think briefly about trying the derivative, but looking at the coefficients it didn't look as though it would produce any more favourable cancellations. The square root is important, I have previously solved withoutout it but it isn't as accurate as I want it to be hence this version. The magnitudes: a & b ~ $10^{10}$, p & q ~ $[10^0,10^2]$, k ~ $10^{-10}$

Comment: I don't know if more context is going to be useful here, but this is trying to solve the question of if an orbit with a given period and field of view is able to completely scan a planet. p/q is the fraction of a sidereal day the orbit takes, a is the semimajor axis of the orbit (actually derived from p, q, the sidereal day, and planetary mass), b is the planet's radius, k is a ratio including the field of view and an altitude.